# Electronic gadget chess opponent for children

Tags: software, learning

I am looking for an electronic gadget that is a chess opponent, designed specially for children. I want to it be touch screen, where the pieces are large enough so you don't need to use a special pen to move the pieces. I also want the gadget to talk often, so the child feels interaction. It could say things like "Good move!", "Great Idea!", and so on.

The closest thing that I've seen is [this](http://www.walmart.com/ip/17477216?adid=22222222227014443039&wmlspartner=wlpa&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=&wl3=13698144550&wl4=&wl5=pla&veh=sem). That thing does not look right, plus 1/5 review, so I was hoping for something better.

Anybody come across anything?

Feel free to edit the tags for my post. I really wasn't sure what to use.

Comment: Does it have to be a standalone device? What about a tablet app?

Comment: @mschultz Tablet app should work too.

Comment: The Walmart link no longer works. Could you replace it with a link that works and add the product name?

Answer (score 2):

This iPad/iPhone [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dinosaur-chess-learn-to-play!/id413237532?mt=8) looks promising based on the reviews. I haven't tried it personally though, so I can't attest to its worth.

[Here](http://www.universis.co.uk/dc/) is the website of the developers. You can contact them to find out more about the features that they have. For instance, I couldn't find anything about whether it would speak to your child.

Comment: This look promising, though I need to look more into it. Thank You.